# write htaccess to dynamic generate id core php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am doing one project in core php, and I have url like theese `www.domainanme.com?proid=125&name=some_name`. How to redirect 404 page error. If I delete id 125(in admin panel) still it shows the page without contents. Can you help me how to write `htaccess` to redirect 404 error page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check in PHP if this item exist and if not - redirect to 404 page. Apache doesn't know anything about your code and I think you return page with 200 HTTP response code and in this case Apache think that all right and show empty page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Error Document in .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```

also consider these best practices.

1. 404s should not be redirected globally to the home page.
2. 404s should only be redirected to a category or parent page. 
   you can do it for subfolders like product folder .htaccess file etc.,
3. and also 404's are not really big problem.If there’s not a good page match for a 404, don’t redirect it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this in htaccess it would be better to do with PHP. Check the `proid` is valid, once not available in db redirect to 404 page using php header function

For eg:-

```
header("Location:404_path.php");
```